# What is the PHP extension_loaded for Zend OP Cache?

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, php-5.5

What is the PHP `extension_loaded` in case of Zend OP Cache? APC has been replaced with Zend OP Cache in PHP 5.5

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's `'Zend OPcache'`.

Comment: How can I confirm? my hosting provider is saying 'OPcache'? But he is not too sure.

Comment: If you have ssh access, I think the value will be the same as if you run `php -m`.